# conditionally split list into 2 sublists, supporting successive passes

Tags: python, functional-programming

I want to progressively filter values from one list into sublists.  Each time a condition matches, I want ignore that value for the next filter.

For example, let's say I want to a) grab items divisible by 3, b) grab odd items and c) keep the rest.

```
li = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I want to get:

```
divby3 = [3,6,9]
odd = [1,5,7]
rest =[0,2,4,8]
```

Is there something in itertools to do this with? I wrote some test code, but it looks like something probably already exists.  The most expressive, and amongst the quickest was:

```
def append_split(li,cond):
    """ list comp appends to 2 separate lists """
    hits, miss = [],[]
    [hits.append(v) if cond(v) else miss.append(v) for v in li]
    return hits, miss

p1_divby3, li = append_split(li, is_3)
p2_odd, p3_rest = append_split(li, is_odd)
```

or its suggested alternative:

```
def looped_append(li, cond):
    """ for-loop to avoid side-effects within list comp """
    hits, miss = [],[]
    for v in li: 
        (hits if cond(v) else miss).append(v)
    return hits, miss
```

Is there a better way in the standard library?

The performance I got (on a 10000 item list) was as follows:

```
timings:
0.00301504 by_filter_prune_set
0.00335598 by_append_split
0.00498891 by_tupling
0.56877589 by_memberships
```

#### Full test code:

```
import sys
from time import time

if len(sys.argv) >=2 :
    li = range(0,int(sys.argv[1]))
    do_compare = False
else:
    li = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    do_compare = True

exp = dict(
    p1_divby3 = [3,6,9],
    p2_odd = [1,5,7],
    p3_rest =[0,2,4,8],
)

def is_3(v): 
    return v and not (v % 3)

def is_odd(v): 
    return bool(v % 2)

def get_result(di):
    return {k:v for k,v in sorted(di.items()) if k in exp}

def by_memberships(li):
    """ SLOWEST.  filter checks that item wasn't previously extracted """
    p1_divby3 = [v for v in li if is_3(v)]
    p2_odd = [v for v in li if is_odd(v) and not v in p1_divby3]
    p3_rest = [v for v in li if not v in p1_divby3 and not v in p2_odd]
    return get_result(locals())

def prune_set(candidates, seen):
    """ filter, then prune found from list."""
    seen = set(seen)  #really slow if you dont cast to a set
    return [v for v in candidates if not v in seen]

def by_filter_prune_set(li):
    p1_divby3 = [v for v in li if is_3(v)]
    li = prune_set(li, p1_divby3)
    p2_odd = [v for v in li if is_odd(v)]
    p3_rest = prune_set(li, p2_odd)
    return get_result(locals())

def looped_append(li, cond):
    # from comments, also slighty faster than append_split
    hits, miss = [],[]
    for v in li: 
        (hits if cond(v) else miss).append(v)
    return hits, miss

def by_looped_append(li):
    p1_divby3, li = looped_append(li, is_3)
    p2_odd, p3_rest = looped_append(li, is_odd)
    return get_result(locals())


def append_split(li,cond):
    """ list comp appends to 2 separate lists """
    hits, miss = [],[]
    [hits.append(v) if cond(v) else miss.append(v) for v in li]
    return hits, miss

def by_append_split(li):
    p1_divby3, li = append_split(li, is_3)
    p2_odd, p3_rest = append_split(li, is_odd)
    return get_result(locals())

def split_tupling(li, cond):
    """ put into a (hit, miss) tuple then re-filter into 2 lists"""
    undefined = NotImplemented
    li = [(v, undefined) if cond(v) else (undefined, v) for v in li  ]
    hits = [v[0] for v in li if v[0] is not undefined]
    miss = [v[1] for v in li if v[0] is undefined]
    return hits, miss

def by_tupling(li):
    p1_divby3, li = split_tupling(li, is_3)
    p2_odd, p3_rest = split_tupling(li, is_odd)
    return get_result(locals())

timings = {}
for fn in [by_memberships, by_looped_append, by_append_split, by_tupling, by_filter_prune_set]:
    sys.stdout.write(f"\n\n{fn.__name__:20.20}")
    start = time()
    got = fn(li)
    duration = time()-start
    sys.stdout.write(f" {duration:10.8f}\n")
    timings[fn.__name__] = duration
    if do_compare:
        if got == exp:
            flag = "✅"
        else:
            flag = "❌"
        print(f"{flag}{exp=}\n{flag}{got=}")

li = sorted([(v,k) for k,v in timings.items()])
print("\n\ntimings:")
[print(f"{tu[0]:010.8f} {tu[1]}") for tu in li]
```

Comment: `[hits.append(v) if cond(v) else miss.append(v) for v in li]` Don't use list comprehensions for side-effects https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753614/843953

Comment: keep in mind `hits` and `miss` are local to the function and initialized to be its return values.  the risk seems low.

Comment: i agree the comprhension is bad, but the logic can be simplified also `for v in li: (hits if cond(v) else misses).append(v)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands that works and is marginally faster than the offending side effects version

Comment: The most close function I can think of is `more_itertools.partition`, though it splits an iterable into 2 depending on a condition. Applying it 2 times will grant you desired result.

Comment: @heinwol Id accept an answer based on it.  I can even provide you the code:  *from more_itertools import partition

def by_partition(li):
    """ using more_itertools.partition(pred, iterable) """

    li, p1_divby3  = partition(is_3, li)
    p3_rest, p2_odd  = partition(is_odd, li)
    return get_result(locals())* .  Timings are *waaaay* better using this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal working example answer using `more_itertools.partition` is below.

```
from more_itertools import partition

li = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def is_3(v): 
    return v and not (v % 3)

def is_odd(v): 
    return bool(v % 2)

def by_partition(li): 
    """ using more_itertools.partition(pred, iterable) """ 
    li2, p1_divby3 = partition(is_3, li) 
    p3_rest, p2_odd = partition(is_odd, li2) 
    return tuple(map(list, [p1_divby3, p2_odd, p3_rest]))

div_by_3, odd, rest = by_partition(li)
```

I can only add that if one encounters such a situation several times it might be good and beautiful to write a more generic function, which splits an iterable into several ones depending on several conditions.

P.S. Thanks for the code!

Comment: You're welcome.  I was surprised there wasn't anything in the std library, but `more_itertools` is pretty close.  In any case, it is wickedly faster on large volumes.